# I can't figure out how to click through an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched up and down google and haven't found a simple solution.

Here is the jist of my code:

```
  var theArray = ["one","two","three","four"];


  $('.next').click(function(){
   // go forward on the array
  })

  $('.back').click(function(){
   // do backwards on the array from the current position
  })
```

so, if the user clicks on `"<button class="next">` I would get an alert of "one", they click on "next" again,  an alert of "two", etc...

Is there a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a second variable to keep track of your index:

```
var theArray = ["one","two","three","four"]; 
var arrayIndex=0;

      $('.next').click(function(){
         arrayIndex++
         if(arrayIndex>=theArray.length)
              arrayIndex=0;
         alert(theArray[arrayIndex]);   
      })

      $('.back').click(function(){
         arrayIndex--
         if(arrayIndex<0)
              arrayIndex=theArray.length-1;
         alert(theArray[arrayIndex]);   
      })
```

Answer (score 5):

Sure:

```
theArray.push(theItem = theArray.shift());
// and...
theArray.unshift(theItem = theArray.pop());
```

`theItem` is the first and last item respectively. Repeated calling of the function will continue cycling the items.

However note that you can't do something like "add another to the end" anymore. To get that, you will need to manually keep track of the "current item", and increment/decrement it instead of cycling the items around.

Comment: pardon the stupidity, but what am I alerting on? Can you elaborate on this a little bit more?